# How do i add names in /tellraw

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a server and when a player joins i want it to say their name. I'm pretty good with commands so you don't have to give me a full command. just in case here is command:

```
/tellraw @p[count=1,y=~1,x=~,z=~,rm=1,r=2] ["",{"text":"[","color":"dark_blue"},{"text":"~","color":"blue"},{"text":"] ","color":"dark_blue"},{"text":"Welcome ","color":"green"},{"text":"[PlayerNameHere]","color":"red"},{"text":", To [Undecided]!","color":"aqua"},{"text":"\n"},{"text":"[","color":"dark_blue"},{"text":"~","color":"blue"},{"text":"] ","color":"dark_blue"},{"text":"[PlayerNameHere] ","color":"red"},{"text":"You must be new! ","color":"aqua"},{"text":"*Click Here*","color":"aqua","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tellraw @a {\"text\":\"Signed In As: {PlayerNameHere} Password:[Random], Do not forget\"}"}},{"text":" To sign Up!","color":"aqua"}]
```

Comment: `@p[count=1,y=~1,x=~,z=~,rm=1,r=2]` won't work, as you can't use relative coordinates in selectors, and it's `c` rather than `count`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `selector` component. For example:

```
/tellraw @a [{"text":"Welcome, "},{"selector":"@p"}]
```

Replace `@p` with the selector you want to use.

Comment: What can i do if i want to add more then just Welcome? I would like to add my server name.

Comment: @Player You should be able to add more text or other components just as you normally would, with a comma and a new element in the list. If there's a command you're trying that isn't working, you could paste it in a comment here.

Comment: I'm not having any problems, so i think i'm good.

Comment: Ok, so, this is my command: /tellraw @a [{"text":"Welcome, "},{"selector":"@p"},{"text":"to [Undecided]!","color":"red"} And it tells me: Invalid json: Unterminated Array at line 1 column 78, btw, i am using 1.10.2

Comment: @Player You need to keep the `]` at the end. E.G: `/tellraw @a [{"text":"Welcome, "},{"selector":"@p"},{"text":" to [Undecided]!","color":"red"}]`